# BrowserSync (w/ gulp) working really slow

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, browser-sync

I'm using browsersync with gulp in my project, and when I had one jade file, one css and one js file it worked fine. But now I have 7 jade files (not so many at all), and every html task & reload takes 5-6 **seconds**.

Here is my gulpfile:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync');
var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var jade = require('gulp-jade');

// Sass
gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return gulp.src(['src/_media/scss/*.scss', 'src/_media/scss/**/*.scss'])
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(autoprefixer({
            browsers: ['last 3 versions'],
            cascade: false
        }))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/_media/css/'))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});

// HTML
gulp.task('html', function() {
    return gulp.src(['src/*.jade', 'src/**/*.jade'])
        .pipe(jade({
            pretty: true
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/'));
});

// Watch HTML
gulp.task('html-watch', ['html'], function(done) {
    browserSync.reload();
    done();
});

// Javascript
gulp.task('javascript', function() {
    return gulp.src(['src/_media/js/*.js', 'src/_media/js/**/*.js'])
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/_media/js/'));
});

// Watch Javascript
gulp.task('javascript-watch', ['javascript'], function(done) {
    browserSync.reload();
    done();
});

// Images
gulp.task('images', function() {
    return gulp.src(['src/images/*.*', 'src/images/**/*.*'])
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/_media/images/'));
});

// Watch Images
gulp.task('images-watch', ['images'], function(done) {
    browserSync.reload();
    done();
});

// Default task
gulp.task('serve', ['html', 'javascript', 'images'], function() {
    browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: './public',
            directory: true
        },
        injectChanges: true,
        notify: false,
    });

    gulp.watch(['src/_media/scss/*.scss', 'src/_media/scss/**/*.scss'], ['sass']);
    gulp.watch(['src/_media/js/*.js', 'src/_media/js/**/*.js'], ['javascript-watch']);
    gulp.watch(['src/images/*.*', 'src/images/**/*.*'], ['images-watch']);
    gulp.watch(['src/*.jade', 'src/**/*.jade'], ['html-watch']);
});
```

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

As for me, you write too much variables.
For instance, instead:

```
return gulp.src(['src/_media/scss/*.scss', 'src/_media/scss/**/*.scss'])
```

u can write only this code below and u will choose all files '.sass' in directory sass

```
return gulp.src('src/_media/scss/**/*.scss')
```

Also try write gulp.task('watch'...)at the bottom and indicate all tasks for which you need to watch.
I tried to rewrite 'gulpfile.js' and I think it will work correctly and fast.
Try and give me to know.

```js
var gulp = require('gulp');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync');
var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var jade = require('gulp-jade');

// Sass
gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return gulp.src('src/_media/scss/**/*.scss')
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(autoprefixer({
            browsers: ['last 3 versions'],
            cascade: false
        }))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/_media/css/'))
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true}))
});

// HTML
gulp.task('html', function() {
    return gulp.src('src/**/*.jade')
        .pipe(jade({
            pretty: true
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/'));
});


// Javascript
gulp.task('javascript', function() {
    return gulp.src('src/_media/js/**/*.js')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/_media/js/'));
});



// Images
gulp.task('images', function() {
    return gulp.src('src/images/**/*.*')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/_media/images/'));
});



// Default task
gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
    browserSync({
        server: {
            baseDir: './public',
            directory: true
        },
        injectChanges: true,
        notify: false,
    });
});


gulp.task('watch', ['browser-sync', 'sass', 'html', 'javascript', 'images'], function() {
    gulp.watch('src/_media/scss/**/*.scss', ['sass']);
    gulp.watch('src/**/*.jade', browserSync.reload);
    gulp.watch('src/_media/js/**/*.js', ['javascript-watch'], browserSync.reload);
    gulp.watch('src/images/**/*.*', ['images-watch'] ,browserSync.reload);
});
```

Comment: Now it's not watching for jade files changes... and when I change this:
`gulp.watch('src/**/*.jade', browserSync.reload);`
to:
`gulp.watch('src/**/*.jade', ['html'], browserSync.reload);`
it takes the same amount of time it took before...

Comment: Hmm. try this `gulp.watch('src/*.jade', ['html'], browserSync.reload);` may be gulp search also jade files in 'node_modules' and it takes a lot of time 

Also look on this template [link](https://github.com/agragregra/jekyll-gulp-autoprefixer-sass-bourbon-jade-browser-sync)

Hope it help u